# How to sort child nodes in Core Data?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a entity in CoreData called TreeNode. 
It have a attribute date as string type.
It have a relationship parent(one to one) and a relationship children(one to many).
It have a fetch method called rootNodes.

[image]

How to sort child nodes in Core Data? (Sorting Year, Month and Day)
Thank you so much.

```
- (NSArray *)rootNodes {

     NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date"   ascending:YES];
     NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parent == nil];
     NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"TreeNode"];
    [request setSortDescriptors:@[sort]];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *objects = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (error)
        NSAssert1(error == nil, @"%s Error occurred!", __func__);

    return objects;
}



superNode(2013-Year)
 |
 +--->subNode(09-Month)
 |
 +--->subNode(01-Month)
 |     +--->subNode(10-Day)
 |     +--->subNode(04-Day)
 |     +--->subNode(03-Day)
 |
 +--->subNode(06-Month)
 |     +--->subNode(18-Day)
 |     +--->subNode(01-Day)
 |     +--->subNode(22-Day)
 |     +--->subNode(02-Day)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is you can't (easily) do it because you are storing the date as a string.  If you were storing the date as a date then your existing code would work.

You might be able to make it work with some clever subclassing and convenience methods.  But first you need to show me the **real** data model, a screen shot, etc. from Xcode will be fine.  The way you have it drawn doesn't make a lot of sense.

Once you post the model I will update this answer with my subclassing suggestion.

### Update 1

What is stored in that string.  Is it actually just year at the top level, month at the next level and then day at the final level?  That is a VERY odd design outside of a school-room example...

If the data really is in that format **and** the single digit numbers start with a zero then your sort that you defined above will work just fine for the top level (year) nodes.  Then you can create a sorting convenience method to return the subNodes:

```
- (NSArray*)sortedSubNodes
{
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
    NSSet *subNodes = [self valueForKey:@"children"];
    NSArray *sortedNodes = [subNodes sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
    return sortedNodes;
}
```

Put that method in your `NSManagedObject` subclass, declare the subclass in the model and you can then get the months in order from the years and get the days in order from the months.

Comment: Hi Master, Thanks for your advance.How about change date type from sting to number or date(NSDate)?

Comment: 'Seconds since a reference date' stored as a number for dates makes it easy to sort on (& query).